# How to check data in Ngrx Store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

The Image shows the data in a store.select call( in chrome debugger ) . 
 ! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w049q.png

I want to check the Data in a store.select( data ) call. But I dont see any.
How do I get the data in the store on hover in chrome debugger.

Comment: why not using the redux DevTools? With that you can monitor the state of the store at any time, event store snapshots of it in the past

Comment: Exactly. Redux Devtools is exactly what you should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting data from store is asynchronous. And to get data - you should know the key name, you want to get. And each time this key in store is changes - your subscribed callback function will run and can assign stored value to some variable

And only after that you can show that variable with assigned value.
For example:

```
let stream$ = Store.select((store) => store.superKey)
let localValue;
stream.subscribe((value) => localValue = value); // will be called each time store.superKey is reassigned with new value


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
//here you can show localValue somewhere.
})
```

Very abstract but hope I've got an idea.